# React Refs Act Differently in Development and Production using Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, framer-motion, react-ref

I'm following this part of this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Yw7yWHigGKI?si=rht5Rzx7kYwF7dCG&t=8758)

(Edit: created a github project showing the issue [here](https://github.com/Zaytt/nextjs-framer-scroll-test), diff behaviors if running dev or prod modes)

(Edit 2: sandbox project showing the differences when running "npm run dev" vs "npm run build + npm start" [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Zaytt/nextjs-framer-scroll-test))

I managed to implement the desired functionality of the scrolling line and the closing circles.
But when deployed to production, the circles seem to be using all the same ref, as they're all synchronized instead of completing independently as the user scrolls down.
Added an imagine placing the behavior side by side to better illustrate whats happening. Again, this only happens when running a production build of the project

[image]

Here's the relevant code of the circles

**ExperienceDetail.tsx**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Job } from './jobList';
import styles from './ExperienceDetail.module.css';
import ListIcon from './ListIcon';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

interface DetailsProps {
  job: Job;
}

const ExperienceDetail: React.FC<DetailsProps> = ({ job }) => {
  const ref = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();
  return (
    <li
      ref={ref as any}
      className={`${styles.detailContainer}`}
      id={job.position}
    >
      <ListIcon reference={ref} />
      <motion.div
        initial={{ y: 50 }}
        whileInView={{ y: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.618, type: 'spring' }}
      >
        <h3 className={`${styles.title} is-capitalized has-text-weight-bold `}>
          {job.position}&nbsp;
          <a
            href={job.companyLink}
            target="_blank"
            className="has-text-primary-dark is-capitalized "
          >
            @{job.company}
          </a>
        </h3>
        <span className="is-capitalized has-text-weight-medium has-text-grey">
          {job.time} | {job.location}
        </span>
        <p
          className={'mt-2 has-text-weight-medium'}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: job.description }}
        />
      </motion.div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default ExperienceDetail;
```

**ListIcon.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ListIcon.module.css';
import { motion, useScroll } from 'framer-motion';

interface ListIconProps {
  reference: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>;
}

const ListIcon: React.FC<ListIconProps> = ({ reference }) => {
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: reference,
    offset: ['center end', 'center center'],
  });
  return (
    <figure className={styles.listIcon}>
      <svg width="75" height="75" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="75" cy="50" r="20" className={styles.circle1} />
        <motion.circle
          cx="75"
          cy="50"
          r="20"
          className={styles.circle2}
          style={{ pathLength: scrollYProgress }}
        />
        <circle
          cx="75"
          cy="50"
          r="10"
          className={`${styles.circle3} ${styles.pulse}`}
        />
      </svg>
    </figure>
  );
};

export default ListIcon;
```

The ExperienceDetail component is being rendered by a map function on a parent component like this

```
<ul>
    {list.map((item, index) => (
        <ExperienceDetail item={item} key={`${type}-${index}`} />
    ))}
</ul>
```

I've tried undoing the map and rendering them directly, but no success.
Also tried swapping the useRef for React.createRef but again, nothing.

What could be causing this difference in behavior between local and production builds?

I've tried undoing the map and rendering them directly, but no success. Also tried swapping the useRef for React.createRef but again, nothing.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem locally by running a production build instead of a dev server?

Comment: Yeah, I can replicate the issue when running a production build

Comment: I don't know your specific issue, but that's a helpful piece of knowledge.  There's a good chance you accidentally wrote your code around a rendering behavior quirk when it's in dev mode.  Notably dev mode runs things like `useState` and `useEffect` *twice* to search for side effects.  It could also be insidious like a race condition showing up in optimization.

Comment: Made a sandbox to better illustrate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Zaytt/nextjs-framer-scroll-test

Answer (score 0):

Worked around the issue by passing scrollYProgress to the LiIcon component instead of passing the ref

```
const Details = ({ position, company, time, address, work }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ['center end', 'center center'],
  });

  return (
    <li
      ref={ref}
      className="my-8 first:mt-0 last:mb-8 w-[60%] mx-auto flex flex-col items-center justify-between"
    >
      <LiIcon scrollYProgress={scrollYProgress} />
```

More info: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/60745

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that because the `ref` variable is passed as a `prop`, React is not re-rendering the `<ListIcon>` Element.

On first render, the `ref` is instantiated, its `current` value is `null`.

`useScroll` falls back to track the `documentElement` when the `target` is null.

Later, the `ref.current` is updated with the `<li>` element, but React has no reason to re-render `<ListIcon>` because the only prop `reference={ref}` hasn't changed.

Remember that `ref`s are stable references, and React only does a shallow comparison of props. So, `<ListIcon>` doesn't rerender when `ref.current` is set.

The `useScroll` hook in `framer-motion` adds the `target` prop as the `useEffect` dependencies, but again, `ref`s are stable references. So the `useEffect` has no reason to update.

https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/main/packages/framer-motion/src/value/use-scroll.ts